# Wrong mouse button state in Form.Deactivate

Tags: c#, winforms, events

When I check the mouse button state in Form.Deactivate, it does not represent the state that must have caused the deactivation of the Form.

In terms of the given example project this means, if the dropDownForm has just been shown (and thus focused) by pressing the button, and I hold down the left mouse button outside dropDownForm's bounding rectangle, the Deactivate event is correctly fired, but inside its handler's body the mouse state is incorrectly shown as MouseButtons.None.

Interestingly, the only exception is when I click on the MainForm's title bar, in which Deactivate is triggered twice, the first occurrence of which is showing the correct mouse button state.

Is there any way to get the mouse button state with a correct result in the Deactivate event?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FormDeactivateTest
{
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        Form dropDownForm;
        Button button1;

        public MainForm()
        {
            button1 = new Button();
            SuspendLayout();

            button1.Location = new Point(107, 54);
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(75, 23);
            button1.TabIndex = 0;
            button1.Text = "Show Form";
            button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            button1.Click += Button1Click;

            dropDownForm = new Form();
            dropDownForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
            dropDownForm.ControlBox = false;
            dropDownForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            dropDownForm.ShowIcon = false;
            dropDownForm.MinimizeBox = false;
            dropDownForm.MaximizeBox = false;
            dropDownForm.HelpButton = false;
            dropDownForm.Text = "";
            dropDownForm.TopMost = true;
            dropDownForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            dropDownForm.Deactivate += dropDownDeactivate;

            AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            ClientSize = new Size(284, 261);
            Controls.Add(button1);
            Name = "MainForm";
            Text = "FormDeactivateTest";
            ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dropDownForm.Visible) dropDownForm.Hide();
            else
            {
                dropDownForm.Location = button1.PointToScreen(new Point(0, button1.Height+1)); 
                dropDownForm.Show();
            }
        }

        void dropDownDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Control.MouseButtons == MouseButtons.None)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mouse button press not recognized");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mouse button pressed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**
If what you are going for is a dropdown panel with arbitrary stuff in it you can use `ToolStripDropDownButton` and `ToolStripControlHost`.  Advantages include:

- it closes itself
- it moves with the form
- it looks more consistent with windows standard designs
- it supports keyboard navigation (Tab, Down etc)
- you have to write less code!

You can even undock it or put it inside another panel if you need it to not appear along the top.

[image]

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
    private ToolStrip toolStrip1;
    private ToolStripDropDownButton toolStripDropDownButton1;

    public MainForm()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
        this.toolStrip1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip();
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDownButton();
        this.toolStrip1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // toolStrip1
        // 
        this.toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.toolStripDropDownButton1});
        this.toolStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1";
        this.toolStrip1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 25);
        this.toolStrip1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.toolStrip1.Text = "toolStrip1";
        // 
        // toolStripDropDownButton1
        // 
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("toolStripDropDownButton1.Image")));
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Name = "toolStripDropDownButton1";
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(29, 22);
        this.toolStripDropDownButton1.Text = "toolStripDropDownButton1";
        // 
        // MainForm
        // 
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 261);
        this.Controls.Add(this.toolStrip1);
        this.Name = "MainForm";
        this.toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.toolStrip1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

        var tv = new TreeView();
        tv.Nodes.Add("test", "testText");
        tv.Nodes.Add("test2", "testTexttt");
        tv.Nodes.Add("test2", "testTexttttttt");
        var hosted = new ToolStripControlHost(tv);
        toolStripDropDownButton1.DropDownItems.Add(hosted);

    }
}
```

**Previous Answer**

The user could trigger `Deactivate` by Alt+Tab away from your form too (which would result in no mouse clicks) so not sure why you would want to do this.

But you could do it with a flag and a listener on OnMouseUp. This doesn't trigger if you click in the parent's border though.

```
private bool recentlyDeactivated = false;
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseUp(e);

    if (recentlyDeactivated)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.None)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse button press not recognized");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Mouse button pressed");
        }
    }

    recentlyDeactivated = false;
}

void dropDownDeactivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    recentlyDeactivated = true;
}
```

Comment: The reason why I want to do this is that this is used in a custom combobox (with a treeview shown in the second/dropdown form). Clicking on the base control (a button in the demo case above) shall toggle the dropdown, clicking outside the dropdown shall close it. But if the dropdown is already shown, both events are triggered and so the form will be closed and opened again immediately. The problem with your approach is that there is no detection of "recently". Any deactivation in the past will keep the flag set. A timer could cure that, but then the minimal timeout value is machine dependent.

Comment: To be honest I was hoping for someone clarifying to me WHY the mouse button state is not reflected correctly and WHERE to read the current value (MouseDevice? Driver?). Because physically it is clearly possible to keep the mouse button pressed while deactivation is still being processed. So it is a matter of latency somehow.

Comment: Just a theory but maybe the windows API is dealing with the mouse down first.  The mouse goes down, Windows get's the callback and changes the window display order and sends dotnet the focus change events (which triggers your callback).  A later event subscriber handles updating the static mouse handler?  There are a lot of ways of changing window focus (Windows+D, Alt+Tab, Alt+Shift+Tab etc) so it makes sense that the activation callback code is seperate from the mouse event handlers and so it's not surprising that one comes first.

Comment: I've updated the answer with what I think is a better solution to your problem if you want a tree view in a dropdown from a button.

Comment: I have already been through ToolStripControlHost, but I did something wrong, as far as I remember I had it free floating instead of attaching it to a button. So I had to do some manual work and there were still some glitches. But now I will give ToolStripDropDownButton a try, which I had not considered originally, because I naively thought I needed to attach the dropdown to an edit box (which is not the case).